# multiple php if and statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I now see what I have to do but have no idea how to do strpos and if together?

what I am trying to do 
`if (strpos($field, 'google') !== false) && ($version == 'ready') {
echo 'true';}`

so basically if $field contains the word google anywhere in it doesn't have to be a perfect match and if $version is equal to ready.

Comment: Are you sure, all these variable has the defined values?

Comment: Check all the variables that they hold the values you expect them to have.

Comment: "It doesn't work"? Error message showing? Computer shutting down? House burning down? Cat dying?

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($number,$version,$field);` and post the results please?

Comment: That code makes sense... If the variables had no value then you'd get an "Undefined variable" error not a syntax error. Are you sure the error corresponds to the same line that you are on?

Comment: I don't why your got that error with that minimal info But this works `$number = 2;$version = "ready";$field = "testing";
if ($number == '2' && $version == 'ready' && $field == 'testing'){
 echo "ok";
}else{
 echo "not ok";
}`

Comment: made some edits please check now

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You need to enclose the condition in parentheses:

```
if (strpos($field, 'google') !== false && $version == 'ready') { echo 'true';}
```